# Passing vectors as a function arguments

Tags: c++, debugging, vector

```
static int sum = 0;
static int loop = 0;

void put_into_vector( ifstream& ifs, vector<int>& v )
{

    // String to store our file input string
    string s;

    // Extracts characters from the input sequence until a delimited is found
    getline( ifs, s );

    // Input string stream class to modify the strings
    istringstream iss( s );

    // Skip all the white spaces. 
    iss >> skipws;

    // Function to check if stream's error flags (eofbit, failbit and badbit) are set.
    if(iss.good())
    {
        // Copies elements within the specified range to the container specified.
        copy( istream_iterator<int>( iss ), istream_iterator<int>(),back_inserter(v));
    }
}

void get_value(vector<int>& v, int start, int end)
{
    while(loop < 4)
    {
        if(start == end)
        {
            sum = sum + v[start];
            loop++;
            get_value(v,start,end+1);
        }
        if(v[start] > v[end])
        {
            sum = sum + v[start];
            loop++;
            get_value(v,start,end);
        }
        if(v[start] < v[end])
        {
            sum = sum + v[end];
            loop++;
            get_value(v,end,end+1);
        }
    }   
}

int main()
{    
    vector<int> triangle_array[4];
    ifstream ifs("numbers.txt");

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        put_into_vector(ifs, triangle_array[i]);
    }

    int row = 0;
    get_value(triangle_array[row], 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to get my code running. The code reads a text file which is as follows:

`5`

`8 1`

`4 8 3`

`0 7 12 4`

When I call the get_value function and pass in the arguments it points to the first vector
which is v[0] = 5. In the first condition when start == end, I update the value of max but after doing this I want to call the same function again but pass the next vector ie. v[1]
which has " 8,1". I cannot do this because it gives me an error on writing v[1] or anything inside it.

The error is: `error C2664: 'get_value' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'`

Do you know of a way I can call it recursively by passing the vec which points to the next row i.e `vec[0]` then `vec[1],vec[2]` and `vec[3]`.

Comment: I want to get the sum of the adjacent elements in the given text file... The triangle puzzle Euler project problem 67.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused as to what you want to do, but I'm guessing it's something like this:

```
//you have
void get_value(vector<int>& v, int start, int end);

//you want
void get_value(vector<int>* v, const int curVectorIdx, const int maxVectors, int start, int end)
{
    int nextVectorIdx = curVectorIdx + 1;
    if(nextVectorIdx < maxVectors) {
        vector<int>* nextVector = v + nextVectorIdx;
        get_value(nextVector, nextVectorIdx, maxVectors, nextVector->begin(), nextVector->end());
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should look at his text file once more. It was not clear what it looked like due to bad formatting. (I reformatted it and hope my reformation will be visible soon).

Comment: Yes this is the correct file. Thanks for the formatting. I want to get the value at the first row, then according to the conditions go the the next row(using vector) and the modified values of start and end. But I am still not able to figure out how to do it

Comment: Not sure what the down votes are for.  Your get_value function is expecting a single vector<int>&.

If you want to get the other rows you'll need to change it to something similar to what I wrote.

It is possible to get the other rows by manually traversing addresses, but you probably shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
get_value(triangle_array[row], 0, 0); this line
```

To this `get_value(triangle_array, 0, 0);`